# Maximum monitor resolution is only 1024*768

Tags: display-resolution

I have a linux box with 2 monitors. The monitors are the same, LG.

It has 2 output, HDMI and D-Sub.

Unluckyly my machine has only one HDMI input. The monitor with the VGA cable has only 1024*768, Ubuntu says it is `Unknown monitor`

I tried this:

```
cvt 1920 1080
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1920x1080_60.00
```

After this I could select the 1920x1080 in the `Control Panel -> Display` for this second monior, but when I tried to apply, it says:

> the selected configuration for displays could not be applied could not
>   set  the configuration for CRTC 63

I switched the two input, the monitor is works perfectly with HDMI cable but not with D-Sub cable.

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE:**

Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

The video card:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

The `xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2944 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 connected 1024x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1024x768      60.00*
800x600       60.32    56.25
848x480       60.00
640x480       59.94
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    50.00    59.94
1680x1050     59.88
1400x1050     59.95
1600x900      60.00
1280x1024     75.02    60.02
1440x900      59.90
1280x800      59.91
1152x864      75.00
1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
1024x768      75.03    60.00
800x600       75.00    60.32
720x576       50.00
720x480       60.00    59.94
640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
720x400       70.08
1920x1080_60.00 (0x142) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96H
```

Comment: VGA does not do EDID, so you you'll have to manually configure the resolution modes, most likely.

Comment: On windows box it works perfectly. I've tried config it manually read my beginning of the post.

Comment: What GPU is being used here? Intel? NVidia? AMD?

Comment: @dobey it is in the post: `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)`

Comment: OK. The CRTC issue is a long standing bug with Intel and multiple displays. Unfortunately, my bug from 2012 on the problem was closed without solution: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51983

Comment: Thx @dobey. I orderd a HDMI - DVI-D cable.

Answer (score 0):

I have one monitor LG 24MP88HV-S with VGA connection and don't know why, but my maximum resolution in KDE monitor settings is only 1024*768.
But output of `xrandr` shows much more modes - maximum `1920x1080     60.00`
This command helped me:

```
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080
```